# I want to make the keys of my dictionaries as rows and the values of those keys of each dictinary as individual columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have multiple dictionaries which have same keys but different values like:

**Dictionary 1**

```
{'00010 – Legislators': ['\n', 'Cabinet minister', '\n', 'City councillor', '\n', 'First Nations band chief', '\n', 'Governor general', '\n', 'Lieutenant-governor', '\n', 'Mayor', '\n', 'Member of Legislative Assembly (MLA)', '\n', 'Member of Parliament (MP)'],
'00011 – Senior government managers and officials': ['\n', 'Assistant deputy minister', '\n', 'Chief administrative officer - regional municipality', '\n', 'Chief statistician - government services', '\n', 'City administrator', '\n', 'Deputy minister'],
'00012 – Senior managers - financial, communications and other business services': ['\n', 'Advertising agency president', '\n', 'Bank president', '\n', 'Chief executive officer (CEO) - telephone company', '\n', 'Chief financial officer (CFO) - advertising agency', '\n', 'Chief operating officer - engineering firm', '\n', 'Computing services company president']....}
```

**Dictionary 2**

```
{'00010 – Legislators': ['Legislators participate in the activities of a federal, provincial, territorial or local government legislative body or executive council, band council or school board as elected or appointed members.'],
'00011 – Senior government managers and officials': ['Senior government managers and officials plan, organize, direct, control and evaluate, through middle managers, the major activities of municipal or regional governments or of provincial, territorial or federal departments, boards, agencies or commissions.'],
'00012 – Senior managers - financial, communications and other business services': ['Senior managers in financial, communications and other business services are usually appointed by a board of directors, to which they report. ']....}
```

**Dictinary 3**

```
{'00010 – Legislators': ['\n', 'Enact, amend or repeal laws and regulations', '\n', 'Participate in developing or amending government policies, programs or procedures', '\n', 'Represent their government at local, national and international meetings and conferences', '\n', 'Respond to matters of concern to constituents or the general public'],
'00011 – Senior government managers and officials': ['\n', 'Establish objectives for the organization in accordance with government legislation and policy, formulate or approve and evaluate programs and procedures alone or in conjunction with senior government committees', '\n', 'Advise elected representatives on policy questions and refer major policy matters to these representatives for final decision'],
'00012 – Senior managers - financial, communications and other business services': ['\n', "Determine the company's mission and strategic direction as conveyed through policies and concrete objectives which are met through the effective management of human, financial and material resources", '\n', 'Authorize and organize the establishment of major departments and associated senior staff positions']....}
```

I am trying to make a dataframe from these dictionaries and the dataframe should look like:

| Job Position | Job Role | Example Titles | Main Duties |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| '00010 – Legislators' | ['Legislators participate in the activities of a federal, provincial, territorial or local government legislative body or executive council, band council or school board as elected or appointed members.'] | ['\n', 'Cabinet minister', '\n', 'City councillor', '\n', 'First Nations band chief', '\n', 'Governor general', '\n', 'Lieutenant-governor', '\n', 'Mayor', '\n', 'Member of Legislative Assembly (MLA)', '\n', 'Member of Parliament (MP)'] | ['\n', 'Enact, amend or repeal laws and regulations', '\n', 'Participate in developing or amending government policies, programs or procedures', '\n', 'Represent their government at local, national and international meetings and conferences', '\n', 'Respond to matters of concern to constituents or the general public'] |
| '00011 – Senior government managers and officials' | ['Senior government managers and officials plan, organize, direct, control and evaluate, through middle managers, the major activities of municipal or regional governments or of provincial, territorial or federal departments, boards, agencies or commissions.'] | ['\n', 'Assistant deputy minister', '\n', 'Chief administrative officer - regional municipality', '\n', 'Chief statistician - government services', '\n', 'City administrator', '\n', 'Deputy minister'] | ['\n', 'Establish objectives for the organization in accordance with government legislation and policy, formulate or approve and evaluate programs and procedures alone or in conjunction with senior government committees', '\n', 'Advise elected representatives on policy questions and refer major policy matters to these representatives for final decision'] |
| '00012 – Senior managers - financial, communications and other business services' | ['Senior managers in financial, communications and other business services are usually appointed by a board of directors, to which they report. '] | ['\n', 'Assistant deputy minister', '\n', 'Chief administrative officer - regional municipality', '\n', 'Chief statistician - government services', '\n', 'City administrator', '\n', 'Deputy minister'] | ['\n', "Determine the company's mission and strategic direction as conveyed through policies and concrete objectives which are met through the effective management of human, financial and material resources", '\n', 'Authorize and organize the establishment of major departments and associated senior staff positions'] |

I have tried:

```
import pandas as pd
mydicts = [job_role, dict_example_titles, dict_main_duties, dict_employment_requirements, dict_additional_info, dict_exclusions]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(mydicts, columns = ['job_role', 'example_titles', 'main_duties', 'employment_requirements', 'additional_info', 'exclusions']) 
#df = pd.concat([pd.Series(d) for d in mydicts], axis=1).fillna(0).T
print(df)
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
columns = ('example_titles', 'job_role', 'main_duties')
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=('job_position', *columns), dtype=object)
for c, d in zip(columns, (dct1, dct2, dct3)):
    for k, v in d.items():
        df.at[k, c] = v
        df.at[k, 'job_position'] = k

print(df)
```

Prints:

| job_position | example_titles | job_role | main_duties |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00010 – Legislators | ['\n', 'Cabinet minister', '\n', 'City councillor', '\n', 'First Nations band chief', '\n', 'Governor general', '\n', 'Lieutenant-governor', '\n', 'Mayor', '\n', 'Member of Legislative Assembly (MLA)', '\n', 'Member of Parliament (MP)'] | ['Legislators participate in the activities of a federal, provincial, territorial or local government legislative body or executive council, band council or school board as elected or appointed members.'] | ['\n', 'Enact, amend or repeal laws and regulations', '\n', 'Participate in developing or amending government policies, programs or procedures', '\n', 'Represent their government at local, national and international meetings and conferences', '\n', 'Respond to matters of concern to constituents or the general public'] |
| 00011 – Senior government managers and officials | ['\n', 'Assistant deputy minister', '\n', 'Chief administrative officer - regional municipality', '\n', 'Chief statistician - government services', '\n', 'City administrator', '\n', 'Deputy minister'] | ['Senior government managers and officials plan, organize, direct, control and evaluate, through middle managers, the major activities of municipal or regional governments or of provincial, territorial or federal departments, boards, agencies or commissions.'] | ['\n', 'Establish objectives for the organization in accordance with government legislation and policy, formulate or approve and evaluate programs and procedures alone or in conjunction with senior government committees', '\n', 'Advise elected representatives on policy questions and refer major policy matters to these representatives for final decision'] |
| 00012 – Senior managers - financial, communications and other business services | ['\n', 'Advertising agency president', '\n', 'Bank president', '\n', 'Chief executive officer (CEO) - telephone company', '\n', 'Chief financial officer (CFO) - advertising agency', '\n', 'Chief operating officer - engineering firm', '\n', 'Computing services company president'] | ['Senior managers in financial, communications and other business services are usually appointed by a board of directors, to which they report. '] | ['\n', "Determine the company's mission and strategic direction as conveyed through policies and concrete objectives which are met through the effective management of human, financial and material resources", '\n', 'Authorize and organize the establishment of major departments and associated senior staff positions'] |